# Fisher yates Shuffle

Tags: java, shuffle

```
static void shuffle(int[] array) {
    int n = array.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        // Get a random index of the array past i.
        int random = i + (int) (Math.random() * (n - i));
        // Swap the random element with the present element.
        int randomElement = array[random];
        array[random] = array[i];
        array[i] = randomElement;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
     int[] values = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};

    // Shuffle integer array.
    shuffle(values);
    // Display elements in array.
    for (int value :values) {
        System.out.print(" " +value);
        //System.out.println(val);
    }
}
```

I want to change the value array by name, for example deni, amir, cintia and others
Help , im newbie

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: I've tried but error

Comment: please help me :(

Comment: Show what you have tried and what error you get.

Comment: I have succeeded in completing it :)

Comment: Gratulations! Happy coding :)

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

```
I have succeeded in completing it :))


 static void shuffle(String[] array) {
    int n = array.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        // Get a random index of the array past i.
        int random = i + (int) (Math.random() * (n - i));
        // Swap the random element with the present element.
        String randomElement = array[random];
        array[random] = array[i];
        array[i] = randomElement;
    }
}
```