# Using Random class to randomize 2d array

Tags: c#, arrays, random

I am trying to randomize a sett of predetermine elements in a 2d array.

```
using System;

namespace array
{
    public class tiles
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int[,] tilearr = { { 0, 1, 2 }, { 3, 4, 5 }, { 6, 7, 8 } };

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(tilearr[i, j] + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is if I do something like `tilearr[i, j] = random.Next(0, 8);` it randomizes the array but doesn't care if there are any duplicates of the same element.

```
2 6 7
1 1 3
2 7 0
```

what I am after is more like this:

```
2 4 8  1 3 0
0 3 1  5 6 8 
6 7 5, 2 4 7
```

Comment: [Shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43876755/1364007) the values instead

Comment: You want to randomize the array but without duplicates?

Comment: If you do not want duplicates, you want to put a set of values (or items) in  random order.  That's called a *shuffle* and there are thousands of posts here on it

Comment: here is a awesome answer from xanatos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164019/shuffling-2d-array-of-cards

Comment: A very easy shuffle algorithm goes something like that: "point" to the last element. Now randomly select an element before that. Exchange those two elements. then "point" to the second to last element and randomly select an element before that and switch those two. and so on, until you "point" to the first element.

Comment: Thanks again for all the fantastic answers, I looked into each and everyone one of them and up-voted all of them sadly I cant pick all of them to be the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user [Wai Ha Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1364007/wai-ha-lee) stated in the comments a shuffle will achieve what you are looking for. I would recommend the Fisher Yates Shuffle.

```
public static void Shuffle<T>(Random random, T[,] array)
{
    int lengthRow = array.GetLength(1);

    for (int i = array.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        int i0 = i / lengthRow;
        int i1 = i % lengthRow;

        int j = random.Next(i + 1);
        int j0 = j / lengthRow;
        int j1 = j % lengthRow;

        T temp = array[i0, i1];
        array[i0, i1] = array[j0, j1];
        array[j0, j1] = temp;
     }
}
```

I retrieved this implementation from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30164383/12720049).

This should be implemented in your code like this,

```
using System;

namespace array
{
    public class tiles
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int[,] tilearr = { { 0, 1, 2 }, { 3, 4, 5 }, { 6, 7, 8 } };
            Shuffle<int>(random, tilearr);

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(tilearr[i, j] + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure to place the shuffle generic function within your class.

[HERE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rRNe2g) is an example of my implementation on dotnetfiddle.net.

Comment: hm I get that the name array doesnt exist ? Did I do something wrong ?

Comment: If you could copy the exact error code or traceback it would help me understand what you mean.

Comment: in the shuffle function `public static void Shuffle<T>(Random random, T[,] array)` it says that name array doesnt exist

Comment: I added an example of my implementation try the code that is in that link to make sure its not a simple error.

Comment: it was just simple error with how the function was created by virtual studio for some reason it wasn't correct and I was on autopilot and just didnt check it sry for the trouble

Answer (score 2):

A simple and to the point solution would be to have a list of available numbers and then go position by position and randomly select the numbers out of the list.

Like this:

```
var numbers = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
for(int x = 0; x < 3; ++x) {
    for(int y = 0; y < 3; ++y) {
        // select a random number from the list ...
        int rand = random.Next(0, numbers.Count - 1);
        tilearr[x, y] = numbers[rand];
        // ... and remove it from the list
        numbers.RemoveAt(rand);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to Randomize would be flatten the 2d array, shuffle it and then recreate based on original dimension. If you want to use Linq/Extension methods, you could do the following

```
Random random = new Random();
int[,] tilearr = {{ 0, 1, 2 }, { 3, 4, 5 }, { 6, 7, 8 }};

var result = tilearr.OfType<int>()
       .OrderBy(x=> random.Next())
       .ChunkBy(tilearr.GetLength(1))
       .To2DArray();
```

Where ChunkBy and To2DArray are defined as

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> ChunkBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int chunkSize) 
    {
        return source
            .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
            .GroupBy(x => x.Index / chunkSize)
            .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value));
    }

    public static T[,] To2DArray<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source)
    {
        var data = source
            .Select(x => x.ToArray())
            .ToArray();

        var res = new T[data.Length, data.Max(x => x.Length)];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; ++i)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < data[i].Length; ++j)
            {
                res[i,j] = data[i][j];
            }
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

[Sample Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/V1PObT)

Answer (score 1):

If you generate the array from scratch, it's easier to randomize a one dimensional array, and then load it into a 2D array.

```
static int[,] GenerateArray(int size)
{
    Random r = new Random();   
    var arr = new int[size, size];
    var values = Enumerable.Range(0, size * size).OrderBy(x => r.Next()).ToArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            arr[i, j] = values[i * size + j];

    return arr;
}
```